# Fleet (Transportration) Dataset

Tags: data-request, geospatial, transportation, traffic, real-time

Is anyone aware of any dataset that is about fleet and fleet management? I mean data about a set of vehicles that transport goods or perform some tasks among different centers within a central management.

I am open to different varieties such as Walmart sending goods to its branches, a postal company, some car manufacturer remotely controlling the cars or even transportation of livestock.

We plan to investigate how technology can improve such businesses from both technological as well as business point of view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exact data you are looking for is kept private as it is a competitive advantage. You have two options on getting the resolution of data you would like:

1. Go work for the business you would like to investigate. Freight companies are secretive about their fleet management. The first reason is to avoid having their competitors get involved and a slight fear of government getting involved.
2. Use simulation softwares from industrial engineers, they can give you a fairly good situation

Open Data Sources:

1. [Freight Analysis Framework](http://www.ops.fhwa.dot.gov/freight/freight_analysis/faf/index.htm): Very high level data

Proprietary Sources:

1. [American Transportation Research Institute's truck data](http://atri-online.org/): This database tracks GPS probes throughout the day from a fairly large database
2. [IHS' TranSearch Database](https://www.ihs.com/products/transearch-freight-transportation-research.html): Provides a higher level of resolution than the FAF system referenced above